# resursive function , index switching to next based on what contained at index i j , C

Tags: c

I am trying to create a recursive function at the bottom of question there is code.

What I am trying to accomplish is

1. through `j` one by one at at index `i` --> if `arr[i][j] !=i` then switch to index number found from the value of `arr[i][j]` at current --> keep doing it recursively and printing current value of `arr[i][j], i,j`

The point of this code is basically input array can be any two dimension array and it should be check that it can be sorted in one special way

so `{{1,3,1},{2,1,2},{3,2,3}}` all three sub-arrays can be sorted to `{{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}}` which is what like to see and check

but in `{{1,3,1},{2,1,1},{3,2,3}}` array index i=1 and i=2 can not be sorted but i=3 can be sorted

So is it possible to do this recursively because I am getting garbage `current_NEq` in `printf`

is there any thing wrong with this code

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int t=0;
int recursive(int i,int n,int m,int arr[n][m],int index,int current)
{

    for(int j=0;i<3;j++)
    {
        if(arr[i][j]!=i)
        {

            printf("i=%d    j=%d  ,    index=%d      current_NEq=%d  \n",i,j,i,arr[i][j]);
            recursive(arr[i][j],n,m,arr,arr[i][j],arr[i][j]);
        }
        else
        {
            t=arr[i][j];

        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int x[][3]={{1,3,1},{2,1,2},{3,2,2}};

    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        recursive(i,3,3,x,(0)+1,0);
    }

    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C arrays are 0 based. `arr[i][x]` where `i == 3` refers to the fourth element of a three element array.

Comment: @Hasturkun is there a way I can keep track of current index. Did u understand my question because i need current index to do this. I have no clue

Comment: If your values are 1..3, you need to subtract one to get an index to access the array with, since the first element is indexed as 0, not 1. As I said above, you're reading past the end of your array. As for the rest of your question, I'm not sure I understood the goal, so won't be commenting on it.

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem correctly, fairly low? Though I suspect that your inner loop shouldn't be in the recursive function (also, your t variable does nothing). I suggest you consider how you'd do this by hand, step by step.

Comment: @Hasturkun Yes I think this is fairly simple if I simple count 1s 2s 3s Ns. But I was looking to do it differently. Like just going inside each index that came in from different values. I dont know how I got this way in mind but I like to do it that way. So that type of recursion cant be used. Keep info about previous stack  variables state in recursive function makes no sense